# Inside interface not recognized on Cisco ASA-5505

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

According to [this documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa80/configuration/guide/conf_gd/cfgnat.html) it should be possible to configure NAT on Cisco ASA. However, when the example command is executed, the input is invalid. A comparable issue occurs while configuring ssh.

**Outcome**

*configure NAT:*

```
ciscoasa# conf t
ciscoasa(config)# nat (inside) 1 X 255.255.255.0
                       ^
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

*configure ssh:*

```
ciscoasa(config)# ssh X 255.255.255.0 inside
                                      ^
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

**No available interfaces**

```
ciscoasa(config)# nat (?

configure mode commands/options:
Current available interface(s):
```

**Version**

```
ciscoasa# sh ve

Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 7.2(4)
Device Manager Version 5.2(4)
```

**Subquestion:** should the *inside* interface be configured?

Comment: What version are you running? In newer versions the syntax is nat (inside,outside) if you want to nat traffic going from the inside to the outside.

Comment: The issue persists: `ciscoasa(config)# nat (inside,outside) 1 X 255.255.255.0
                          ^
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.`

Comment: @DanielDib Software Version has been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [this documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/conf_gd/int5505.html) and executing the following commands:

```
ciscoasa# conf t
ciscoasa(config)# interface vlan X
ciscoasa(config-if)# nameif inside
INFO: Security level for "inside" set to 100 by default.
ciscoasa(config-if)# security-level Y
ciscoasa(config-if)# ip address Z 255.255.255.0
ciscoasa(config-if)# no shutdown
ciscoasa(config-if)# end
```

interfaces were available:

```
ciscoasa# conf t
ciscoasa(config)# nat (?

configure mode commands/options:
Current available interface(s):

  inside  Name of interface VlanX
```

and the commands specified in the question could be executed.